# How to start versioning a composer package?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, semantic-versioning

I'm starting to develop a package that i'd like to open source and use in future projects. I don't understand the proper steps to get this started though.

I've just created the repository on github and here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "ProgrammingAreHard/Arbiter",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Convenience library to manipulate Symfony ACL's",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "David Adams",
            "email": "adams.david.10@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "ProgrammingAreHard\\Arbiter": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/security": "2.4.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "target-dir": "ProgrammingAreHard/Arbiter",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around versioning though. I haven't made any git tags. I've put the `branch-alias` on just because i hear that it's a good practice. I'm not sure `1.0.x-dev` is what should be there right now.

What should i do at this point? I'm not at a point where i'm comfortable with a 1.0 version. Should i create a lightweight or annotated git tag at something like "v0.1.0" immediately or wait until i'm at a point where it's fully functional?

What should i be doing so that it's not a headache later?

I'm assuming composer uses git tags for versioning(?)

Comment: There are no rules. Start with 0.1.0 for now and think about what criteria you want to have for incrementing that. Read up on how popular projects do versioning and copy a model which suits you.

Comment: The rules are basically that the third number in the version triple is incremented on any minor change that is invisible on the surface, like e.g. fixing a bug. The second one is incremented when you add a feature but remain backward compatible. The first one is reserved for major overhauls that break/change public interfaces. When incrementing a number, zero those behind it. The point is that you can always replace X.Y.Z with X.Y.(Z+1) and usually also with X.(Y+1).W, but not with (X+1).V.W.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In doubt (since you can chose any policy you want), you can refer to [semantic versioning 2.0](http://semver.org/)

> Major version zero (`0.y.z`) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time.
>   **The public API should not be considered stable**.

As long as your public API can change, stay in `0.x.y`.

Comment: when i do tag a version, should it be lightweight or annotated?

Comment: @David if you intent to publish (push) that tag, it should be annotate. Light-weight are purely local tags that won't be pushed to an upstream repo.

Comment: sweet. thanks. Do you know where i can read about the `@` sign in version names? I've seen that before but never understood it. ex: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

Comment: @David Do you mean "version contraints"? (as in http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_versions.html#run-lists)

Comment: @David Or do you mean the "Peg and revision" url scheme? As in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html (`svn command -r OPERATIVE-REV item@PEG-REV`)